# show text in popup does not show the correct data

Tags: javascript, html, css

Using JS to create the table with the data for the rows coming from an API. The last cell in each row has a button that should display a popup with results when clicked.

```
                newCell = newRow.insertCell();
                var button_results = document.createElement("button");
                button_results.innerText = 'view results';
                button_results.value=jobs_data[i]["Results"];
                button_results.addEventListener("click", function(){
                    display_popup_in_results(button_results);
                }, false);
                newCell.appendChild(button_results);
```

The above part creates the cell.

```
    function display_popup_in_results(button_results){
        document.getElementById("popup_content").innerHTML=button_results.value;
        const modal = document.querySelector('.modal-wrapper');
        modal.style.display = 'block';
        var close_btn = document.querySelector('.modal-close');
        close_btn.addEventListener('click',hide_popup_in_results);
    }
```

The above is the JS function. Howevern no matter what row you click, it always shows the value of the last row.

The resulting td is laso incorrect and does not include the onclick.

```
<td><button value="1">view results</button></td>
```

Comment: IMO, this is ideal problem of getting last value of array in `for-loop`. Simple fix would be to use `let` instead of `var`.